# Why doesn't Chrome or Firefox auto-highlight the address bar?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

In Windows, when you click on the address bar, it automatically highlights *all* of the web address so you can enter another one without having to drag across everything. I've noticed that it doesn't do that in Chrome or Firefox (I don't know about other browsers). This is very annoying, especially when the site has a long address that goes past the end of the address bar. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can change the behavior to your liking in 'about:config' as suggested below, but it doesn't need fixing. The default setting it correct.

Comment: The *reason* it normally requires a double click to highlight the text is interface consistency. Where else is text highlighted on a single click?

Comment: Auto-selecting the entire URL with a single click is a ***HORRIBLE** mis-feature*.  Why did you move to Ubuntu if you want everything to work like it does on Windows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In firefox, you can change this configuration setting through the "about:config" command.

In the address bar, type in and go to:

```
about:config
```

Click on the "I'll be careful, I promise" radio button.  And input in the following query into the filter:

```
browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll
```

Double click on the entry to toogle its value between true and false.  Select "False" if you want to place the cursor at the insertion point, and select "True" if you want to highlight the entire address bar on a single mouse click.

Here is a link to an article that gives some more useful "about:config" hacks:

[28 Coolest Firefox About:Config Tricks](http://maketecheasier.com/28-coolest-firefox-aboutconfig-tricks/2008/08/21)

Comment: Thanks, that was also useful for macOS, but to disable this behavior as on pasting from the clipboard manager flycut the address bar it looses focus when the overlay was shown to select from clipboard history and on pasting everything in the address bar got selected and removed in the same instance.

Comment: Is there a similar setting for the search bar?  I turned browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll to false on Windows which fixed my address bar, but the search bar still selects all when I click into it.

Comment: This configuration no longer has any effect, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1621570

Answer (score 5):

Double click on on the address bar, and it will select the address.

Comment: by default. Firefox's `about:config` setting is:  `browser.urlbar.doubleClickSelectsAll ; true` so the third cilck is not needed, but that extra click doesn't upset the full selection... I don't know about Chrome (because I don't use it :)...

Comment: @fred on my system (at some times) double click didn't work :P - it does now though so it must have been a problem with my profile. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl-L selects the location bar. After selecting you're going to type anyway so I don't find the process objectionable.

Comment: Also, F6 will highlight the bar in Chrome, and F6 then Tab will also do that in Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> highlights the address.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason that clicking doesn't highlight the entire address is to facilitate partial selection of the URL.

For example on this page you may wish to select the question ID, which you can do with a simple double-click.

Or you may wish to delete everything after the domain, to return to the home page (assuming there is no "home" link). Or copy just the domain for whatever reason.

Comment: Good comment, but it's not an *answer*; otherwise I'd vote this up.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh How is it not an answer? The question is **why** don't browsers auto-highlight; my answer provides a reason.

Comment: If you read the entire post, it's clear the person wants a solution to their problem, not a reason as to why the UI is setup differently than they expect.

Answer (score 0):

on firefox  in address bar enter

```
about:config

browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll
to  true

browser.urlbar.doubleClickSelectsAll
to  false
```

benefit of this solution is it not only highlights URL it also copies into clipboard ... at least on linux dunno about other OS